powershell - distance (meters) between coordinates
How to get distance between a-b coordinates in meters using powershell?
a)
xx.xxxxxx
xx.xxxxxx
b)
xx.xxxxxx
xx.xxxxxx
Every example i see uses java script or c#
Many thanks!

meters are just decimal numbers so... just use a subtraction?

For translating global coordinates to spherical surface distance, use the Haversine formula:
# define coordinate degree values
$a = 55.741590, 37.614059 
$b = 55.741728, 37.601681

# translate degrees to radians
$p = [math]::PI / 180.0
$lat1 = $a[0] * $p
$lon1 = $a[1] * $p
$lat2 = $b[0] * $p
$lon2 = $b[1] * $p

# calculate difference between points on each axis
$lat_diff = $lat1-$lat2
$lon_diff = $lon1-$lon2
  
# calculate distance of great-circle arc between the two points
$n = [math]::Pow([math]::Sin($lat_diff/2), 2) + [math]::Cos($lat1) * [math]::Cos($lat2) * [math]::Pow([math]::Sin($lon_diff/2), 2) 
$n = 2 * [math]::Asin([math]::Sqrt($n))
  
# multiply relative arc distance by (approximate average) radius of the earth in meters to get human-readable distance
$r = 6.371 * 1e6

$d = $r * $n

$d now contains the approximate distance in meters - with the coordinates copied from the Yandex directions you linked to I get ~775m.

For 2D systems you can use the Pythagorean theorem to calculate the Euclidean distance between two coordinates:
$a = 1.0, 1.0
$b = 10.0, 4.0

# calculate square of distances on each axis
$x_d = [math]::Pow($a[0] - $b[0], 2)
$y_d = [math]::Pow($a[1] - $b[1], 2)

# result is the root of the sum of squares
$d = [math]::Sqrt($x_d + $y_d)

$d now contains the distance between the two coordinates

Sory cant understand . $a = 55.820641, 37.61026 ;$b = 55.820635, 37.614448 . .what is that result 0.00418800429799836 ?

@IgorKuznetsov I'm sorry, I don't understand what it is you don't understand. The result you get looks correct to me

how to get meters from it ?:)

@IgorKuznetsov that depends on the units of your coordinate system. If 1 unit is 1 meter, then the answer is 0.004188...

bad example.  55.741741, 37.601690  55.741590, 37.614059 -- distance is 777m https://yandex.ru/maps/213/moscow/?ll=37.609029%2C55.742261&mode=whatshere&rl=37.601690%2C55.741761~0.012369%2C-0.000192&whatshere%5Bpoint%5D=37.614059%2C55.741590&whatshere%5Bzoom%5D=16.26&z=16.26 . but in script its 0.0123699216650709 . where is 777m?

@IgorKuznetsov Sorry, I completely misunderstood your question, I thought you were asking about euclidean distance in a flat cartesian system - I'll update with the answer for spherical coordinates :)

@IgorKuznetsov Updated :)
